# Thunderbird hides e-mails

Tags: email, thunderbird

I'm using thunderbird. It just happened that I clicked some keys, and now thunderbird is hiding several mails from me.

Strangely, it still shows them to be found when i search for them (in the examples below, it shows 5 or 21 results, respectivly; but only 1 or 0 mails are displayed).

[image]
[image]

I think it has something to do with "Themenbäume" (dont know the english word), because just after I hit those "magic keys", there has been a strange sign in the "Themenbäume"-row.

I was searching google, but didn't find similar problems yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got an answer [at this page](https://www.thunderbird-mail.de/index.php/Thread/71583-Thunderbird-versteckt-e-Mails/). The problem was a broken "INBOX.msf". One can solve that easily with right-click -> Properties -> Repair.

It might have happend as my INBOX is huge (~8.000 mails and ~3GB). One should copy emails from the inbox to other folders.